Android Studio. Непонятный отступ после 4-х строчек в Edit Text
Edit Text в моем случае при заполнении поля переносит текст на следующую строчку и расширяется в длину. Но после 4 таких строчек появляется большой отступ, как если бы я вводил пустые строчки или ставил paddingBottom. Я новичок, не бейте пожалуйста, простая проблема.

xml окна Dialog:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/taskPopupName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratlight"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:hint="Название"
            android:textColorHint="@color/textgray"
            android:background="@color/trans"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:maxLines="20"
            android:gravity="top"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/taskPopupDesc"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratlight"
            android:textColor="@color/textgray"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:hint="Описание"
            android:textColorHint="@color/textgray"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_gray"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:maxLines="20"
            android:gravity="top"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/popupBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserratlight"
            android:text="ДОБАВИТЬ"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

Функция поп апа в коде:
fun taskPopUp(){
  val b = TaskPopupBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
  val taskdialog = Dialog(this)
  taskdialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
  taskdialog.setContentView(b.root)
  taskdialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)

  taskdialog.show()}

